# Best way to learn the NUnit The Constraint Model?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I find it a bit hard and troublesome to choose which of all the available methods in the NUnit **constraint model** to use.

When I try to use it, I often manage to get it to compile, but it crashes during execution, making me not trust the tests I write.

Using the classic approach, I had better confidence that the tests I wrote would work (yes, I don't want to return to the classic approach).

Is there any good overview and some guidance on how to choose among all of the available constraints? or guidance on **how to think** when choosing among all these methods? (theres **Is.**, **Has.**, **Does.**...)

the official documentation is mostly a reference, so it's not that helpful. I almost wish there was a mindmap chart of all these constraints and which can be used where.

Comment: If you could add some specific code examples, it might be easier to help you here. In retrospect, I think a single "prefix" class would have made it easier to use, even though it would not sound as nice when read aloud. :-)

Comment: It's more of a general question, as I find it hard to get a good mental picture of all the possibilities here and how I should approach all the options. Just finding a list of all the possible start words (Is, Has, Does, Contains, Throws...)  is hard and not even found in the documentation.

Comment: You might consider contributing a page to the documentation. I'm sure the current NUnit team would appreciate it! It doesn't even need to be complete... if you get a page out there it will be improved by others.